# How to mark AWS SES emails so that Gmail filters will match it

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, gmail, amazon-ses

I'm using AWS SES to automate process of sending emails to my customers. I've confirmed my email address in AWS SES, so that it will use my email as a sender & reply to address. Sending works fine, customers are getting emails, but I'd like to have all emails send by AWS SES in my Gmail inbox.

My idea for that was to add BCC with my address to emails, so that email copy is being send to my Gmail inbox. The problem is that when I send a lot of emails my inbox gets messed. Because of that I wanted to mark all AWS SES incoming emails with some label to put them in separate directory. My problem is how to setup Gmail filters & AWS SES emails so that only emails send from AWS SES matches. I tried with setting `from:` filter to my address, but then all sent mails matches also, which is strongly unwanted behaviour. Do you have any better idea to have sent mails on inbox in a clean manner?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well you have probably set up the email topic yourself in SES. Therefore you can create a filter in gmail for a specific topic this way, just copy/paste your topic into the parenthesis:

```
subject:(Your Topic)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Topic is not a good option because it's quite generic and I don't want to match also manually sent emails. I'm looking for something more low level, and perfectly not visible for Gmail user. I saw there are mail headers but I wasn't able to write Gmail filter for them.